# Razor helpers - strange InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

There is a **Common.cshmtl** file containing Razor helpers in **App_Code** folder of my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

The page view (let it be called **Production.cshtml**) uses lots of helpers from Common.cshmtl in the way like:

```
@Common.Helper1();
...
@Common.Helper2();
...
@Common.Helper3();
```

It is following the recommendations from http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site

Due to the bug in application code I can see that 2 almost equal AJAX requests are performed after a button click on a page.

I'm getting an error

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.
```

An error also claims that the code is trying to modify the collection inside **foreach** operator. Here it looks like a normal error of application code.

But when debugging the code to find a certain error I can see that it breaks in some very random place of **Product.cshtml** not connected to the **foreach** at all. No foreach could be found neither in upper-level and bottom-level files. Also when trying to debug again (without modifications of course) - I can see that the break occured this time in another file - in **Common.cshtml** !
Repeating again and again prooves this strange behavior.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Where's the exception details?

Comment: @Will they are in russian :-) i'll translate shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that you are using the wrong guide for MVC 5. An ASP.NET webpages project uses a different structure, you don't need to put your HTML helpers in the `App_Code` folder, and they should be in a `.cs` file, not a `.cshtml` file.

See the following tutorials for help on building MVC HTML helpers.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/787320/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-HTML-Helpers-and

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/N50P050314-Understanding-HTML-Helpers-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d98ae4/creating-custom-html-helpers-in-mvc5/

Comment: so you mean that recommendations specified are incorrect?

Comment: They are incorrect for ASP.NET MVC 5. The link that you posted is for ASP.NET WebPages, which is a different platform that also happens to use Razor syntax.

Comment: that's the point. Anyway, I feel ok to refactor this code. But the question it mostly on what could be reason for this behavior

Comment: And this is the answer to that question. You are building HTML helpers for the wrong platform. You need to follow the MVC HTML helper guides, not the ASP.NET WebPages guides. That is assuming the first part of your question that states you are using ASP.NET MVC 5 is correct.